# How to restrict parse config parameter visible to clients?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Is there any way to remove certain `ParseConfig` parameters that a client (Android, iOS) receives with `ParseConfig.getInBackground(...)`?

The idea is that certain config parameters are used server-side in cloud code and should not be visible to clients, while other parameters are used to configure the client.

Comment: There is no way to do this. Anyone with the API key can read the global config. You can use a class to do this though.

Comment: Yes, a class is a good workaround. I suppose ACLs for config parameters would be an interesting PR.

Comment: Yes. It may be a good idea. Do you mind to open an issue in the Parse Server repo so we can discuss there?

Comment: Done: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/5930

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has since been solved by allowing to restrict individual Parse Config parameters to be accessible only with the master key.

[image]

See https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/5930.

Answer (score 2):

- To have up-to-date settings in your cloud code, you will need to call `Parse.Config.get()` every time, but the main behavior of `Parse.Config.get()` is to retrieve all configuration objects, it's not really an optimized solution.
- `Parse.Config` is designed to be an easy, fast and lightweight solution for obtaining a configuration for clients (public data). If you need to store a `sensitive` configuration, it is not a good idea to store public and sensitive data in the same place.

#### A suggestion for your use case

```js
// Not optimized: The full config is pulled from DB
const config = await Parse.Config.get()

// Not tested: Optimized and secure, (name field should be indexed), InternalConfig need to be protected by CLP
const getInternalConfig = async (...args) => {
    const config = {}
   (await (new Parse.Query('InternalConfig'))
        .containedIn('name', args)
        .find({useMasterKey: true}))
        .forEach(result => config[result.get("name")] = config[result.get("value")]
    return config
}

const optimizedConfig = await getInternalConfig("parameter1", "parameter4" )
```